How do we deal with this spot?
We are new owners of a townhouse. This weird spot is present on the wall that splits a shared deck with our neighbor. What is it? How do we properly maintain out portion of the deck?


Welcome. Please take the [tour]. Protip: Don't announce that you have a question in your title. Ask it. You seem to be asking two distinct things here. Is your question about the hole in the wall or deck maintenance? Please see [ask], then revise to be more specific and clear. Just looks like a scuff and a water stain to me.

Agreed, that looks like something oily scuffed the wall. Maybe the previous owners let a grilling tool drop there.  It does not look to have any structural consequence.  Purely cosmetic. Use some spray cleaner to clean it off.

Thanks so much for your responses!

If it's low on the wall, it could just be a mark from a rubber shoe sole or a grill tire or something of that sort. Context, and a closer photo, would make guessing easier. But I don't think we can do more than guess from a distance
